# Total reflection but still a non-zero probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, potential, reflection

Consider the standard problem of the step potential in Quantum Mechanics.

One writes the Ansatz and using the boundary conditins finds the coefficient amplitides.

If $A$ is the coefficient for the incoming wave and $B$ for the one reflected from the potential step. It is trivial to show that the co-efficient for reflection $R=\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}$ comes out to be unity.

Physically this means that the wave is *totally reflected* but we know that some part of the wave sneaks beyond the step decaying exponentially.

This decay being exponential never quite makes the escaped wave zero though negligible quite soon.

How is some part of the wave sneaking beyond when the wave is getting reflected totally?

I've been told by some friends that this is nothing new and in fact happens even in a non-quantum setting to any wave and it is natural that wavefunctions being 'waves' behave this way.

My issue though is not why quantum mechanically such a thing happens. This is coming out from Schrodinger's equation and the fact that there are waves.

My question is, in general, when we see this phenomenon with waves what are we exactly calculating physically with $R$ ?

Does $R$ coming out 1 not mean that no part of the wave can be present beyond the step? If not what does it tell us?

In other words, what do we mean when say that the whole wave is getting reflected? Certainly in the step potential case there is decaying wave function.

Comment: The wave function being non zero implies there is non zero probability of finding the particle beyond the barrier. Despite that there will be no transmission because probability approaches zero as you go further. Also, as far I as I know this is analogous to the classical phenomenon of evanescent waves in conductors.

Comment: It just means that you can intercept the wave behind the reflector if you probe the evanescent part of it, as in [frustrated total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustrated_total_internal_reflection#FTIR_(Frustrated_Total_Internal_Reflection)). In this case actual reflection coefficient will be less than 1.

Comment: @Ruslan "It just means that you can intercept the wave behind the reflector" But how can one intercept something which is totally reflected back? Shouldn't that mean there is nothing going through?

Comment: As long as you do not intercept  the wave behind the reflector, the wave will be totally reflected back. But if you do intercept the wave, then it will not be totally reflected.

Comment: @md2perpe But in the step potential case the reflection co-efficient is 1 independent of anything. It mathemativally comes out to be 1 and cant depend on cases of me intercepting. In other words, there is nothing in the expression of R that conveys it to change when I intercept the wave behind the reflector.

Comment: @md2perpe Roger Vadim has summarized my question in his answer in a way that clearly highlights what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand the question is the following: suppose we have a potential step, finite in height, but extending to infinity, e.g.,
$$
V(x)=\begin{cases}0, x<0,\\V_0>0, x\geq 0.\end{cases}$$
Then, an electron incident from the left with energy lower than the potential step
$$E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}<V_0$$
will be fully reflected, i.e., the flux flowing from left to right is the same as the flux flowing from right to left. What the OP finds surprising is that we still have an exponentially decaying solution in the step itself, as
$$
\psi(x)\propto e^{-q x},\;q=\frac{1}{\hbar}\sqrt{2m(V_0-E)}.
$$

This decaying solution simply characterizes the manner of scattering - it will have different form for different shapes of the step potential and determine the phase of the reflected wave, but it does not change the fact that the wave is fully reflected.

This is true not only for waves (as the OP notes), but for any scattering event. If we think, e.g., about a tennis ball being scattered from a wall, we have no doubt that the wall is deformed by the ball, and this deformation may extend far to the wall (may be to infinity - depending on how one models the problem). Moreover, the ball penetrates to some depth into the wall before reversing the direction of its motion.

What is really different about wave-like phenomena, is that scattering emerges as a static solution of wave equations, extended in space and without variation in time. Although one can get closer to the mechanical analogy by considering scattering of wave packets.

**Updates**
**Flux vs. probability density**
The answer above was written assuming that the math is well understood, as implied by the OP. Still, for completeness it is necessary to point out that we distinguish here two things:

- non-zero probability of finding the particle in some region of space,
  $$|\psi(x)|^2dx,$$
- non-zero flux
  $$j(x)=\frac{-i\hbar}{2m}\left[\psi^*(x)\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}-\frac{d\psi^*(x)}{dx}\psi(x)\right]$$

It can be easily shown that the eigenfunctions in this problem are real (up to a constant complex phase), which means zero flux, i.e.,

- non-propagation for $x>0$
- full reflection for $x<0$

**Electromagnetic analogy**
A close equivalent of this problem is reflection of an electromagnetic wave from a metal. If the metal is ideal (i.e., all the electric field inside is immediately screened), then there is no field inside the metal, and the wave is fully reflected. If the metal ahs finite conductivity, then there is an exponentially decaying field within the metal ([skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)), but the reflection is still complete. The equivalent of flux in this problem is the Poynting vector.

Comment: "but it does not change the fact that the wave is fully reflected" But again if it is fully reflected how come some part leaks? Are you saying that the part that leaks also comes back? This is seemed to be implied in this line "penetrates to some depth into the wall before reversing the diretcion of its motion."

Comment: So the wave leaks/penetrates and then changes it's direction to come back?

Comment: @Lost How do you expect it to change its direction? Instantly? Could it really be anything else?

Comment: I see what you mean. The waves leak a little and then change direction so to say.  The bothering point then is that even if the leaked wave decays rapidly it actually extends till infinity (since the exponential never reaches zero). So does the whole part that extends to infinity returns? Isn't that a little bothering? For a ball hitting a wall I would say that some part of the impact actually keeps travelling inside the ball even if really small. The ball itself returns with a slightly lower energy.

Comment: @Lost there are different levels of approximation of reality: the ball and the wall have inner degrees of freedom, so some energy is converted into heat. Also, the wall may start moving, taking some of the kinetic energy of the ball . Here the right analogy is the elastic collision and a very heavy wall, so that the ball will be scattered back with the same energy that it had. But this does not happen on a spot - it pushes into the wall, which exerts a force on the ball slowing it down and then accelerating it backwards.

Comment: What happens if you try to detect particles close to the potential step where the amplitude is still relatively high?

Comment: @md2perpe You can detect them - in the quantum case this is known as [*tunneling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling).

Comment: @RogerVadim. How about the reflection rate? Is that still 100%?

Comment: @md2perpe it is not the same system - you will have to modify the potential to measure. In fact, you will be projecting on the states that are not the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian that we are discussing. In equivalent electriomagnetic problem - reflection from a metal, one would assume that the detector only weakly perturbes the field... but then the reflection is 100% up to this error.

Comment: In a comment above I wrote "As long as you do not intercept the wave behind the reflector, the wave will be totally reflected back. But if you do intercept the wave, then it will not be totally reflected." Do you agree?

Comment: @md2perpe I think the statement is imprecise, so one cannot agree or disagree with it. 1) It is fundamental to quantim mechanics that measurement changes the system - this system, including the measurement device, might well have propagating modes. 2) The non-zero probability of detection in some point of space does not mean that the wave is propagating. Propagation means non-zero flux. Using the ball example above - sure, if it gets stuck in the wall, it is not reflected - but this is not what we discuss.

Comment: That's what I mean; if one tries to detect the particles behind the reflector, then the conditions, specifically the potential, are changed, and the earlier calculations showing a 100% reflection, are not valid anymore.